# Grouped bar-plot/ Clustered column chart from a text file in R

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, text, bar-chart

I was planning to plot clustered column chart for the values in 12 stations, from a text file. The plot would therefore be divided into 12 groups. I was easily able to do in excel:

[image]

But i am having troubles doing it with ggplot2 from the text file, this is the code i used:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

my_data <- read.table("MLD.txt",header = T)

attach(my_data)

my_data

head(my_data)

df <- melt(my_data, id.vars=1)


ggplot(df, aes(Station, value)) + geom_bar(
  aes(fill = variable),
  width = 0.4,
  position = position_dodge(width = 0.5),
  stat = "identity"
) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.title =
      element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank()
  )
```

That returns me with this figure:
[image]

As you can see, rather than showing the bars as groups, it is depicting values. I would be grateful if anyone could suggest me, how would I be able to generate the graph similar to excel. I am attaching the original data here, although i'd prefer plotting from the text or csv file:

```
Station   MLD.IN  MLD.MOD
1        1  7.13333 10.52890
2        2  7.93404 10.52890
3        3  4.62014  8.75782
4        4  1.14347  9.06654
5        5  6.45909 10.52890
6        6  5.76597 10.52890
7        7  7.77065 10.05040
8        8  8.64324  7.20295
9        9  8.23878 10.52890
10      10  8.38739 10.48650
11      11 13.40270 10.52890
12      12 18.58280  8.97171
```

Any help, advices would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Do `df$Station <- factor(df$Station, levels=1:12, labels= paste0("Stn ", 1:12))` then re-generate the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a close reproduction of the Excel chart, you could do something like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

my_data <- read.table("MLD.txt",header = T)

df <- melt(my_data, id.vars = 1)

df$Station <- paste("Stn", df$Station)
df$Station <- factor(df$Station, levels = unique(df$Station))

ggplot(df, aes(Station, value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 20), breaks = 0:10 * 2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#599bd7", "#ed7d32")) +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Chart Title") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.title = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "gray50"),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 24, hjust = 0.5)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked this time. Although i understood most part of your code, it'd be great if you maybe briefly explain these couple of lines ```df$Station <- paste("Stn", df$Station)
df$Station <- factor(df$Station, levels = unique(df$Station))```

Comment: Sure @asheef_ik. The text you imported had numbers for `Station` which R interprets as numbers on a continuous scale. But you need each station recognised as a discrete entity. In R we can do this by sticking the character string "Stn" in front of each number using `paste`. To ensure that these are still ordered stn 1 to stn 12, we convert to a factor, which allows us to specify the ordering.

Comment: Thanks again for clearly explaining it. I did a few tweaks to the themes, labels and overall it looks more than fine now.